# Check that a given date does not lie between two existing dates inside a datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database, linq

I have one table which can store student leave start date and end date 
like so:

```
StudentID   Age   startDate   EndDate

1           14    5/05/2013   7/05/2013   
4           17    4/04/2012   8/10/2012
```

I need to check to see if any new leave which is applied for doesn't fall in the range of leave already arranged for that student.  For example, for the student with ID = 1, they should not be able to apply for leave which starts on 6/05/2013.

I'm using c# and am looking for a solution which uses SQL or LINQ.

Comment: "SELECT Count(*) FROM [TableName] WHERE StudentID=@StudentID AND (startDate > @dateToCheck OR EndDate < @dateToCheck)". If count > 0 the `dateToCheck` is either less than (or equal) to `startDate` or greater than (or equal) to `EndDate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

normal SQL 
   Select count(*) from table where StudentID  = 'parameterID' and startDate  <= 'Parameter_StartDate' and EndDate <='Parameter_EnsDate';

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dtApplied;
var allDates = yourDt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Where(x => dtApplied >= x.Field<DateTime>("startDate") && dtApplied <= x.Field<DateTime>("endDate"));
```

However I would consider using `BETWEEN` in `SQL` if I were you.

Comment: i want to check for particular student using their studentid not for all

Comment: Add a condition in the where for that field then, or filter the procedure - this isn't clear in your question. You can do some stuff yourself, you know

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
  var result = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(r =>((int)r["StudentID"])==stdID &&
                                       (DateTime)r["startDate"]<=yourStartDate &&
                                       (DateTime)r["EndDate"]=YourEndDate))
                                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

Or you can do this also:

```
string query="ID=1 AND startDate<=yourStratDate AND EndDate>=yourEndDate";
DataRow [] dr=dt.Select(strQuery);
```

Comment: What do the `StartDate` and `EndDate` variables represent?

Comment: These are the variable for criteria of `StartDate` and `EndDate`. Check the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

```
select student_id From TableName Where Student_id = 1 and @dateToCheck not( between startdate and enddate)
```